# Unable to install npm package: can't find package.json

Tags: android, json, node.js, angularjs

The error:

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies 
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT,open 'C:\Users\Yashizho\Desktop\server\package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likelt not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\node\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Yashziho\Desktop\server
npm ERR! node-v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm-v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Yashizho\Desktop\server\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!   C:\Users\Yashizho\Desktop\server\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: any output in your log files?

Comment: and do you have a C:\Users\Yashizho\Desktop\server\package.json file ? ...

Comment: which pachage you tried to install?